# Format Kendo Grid to display dollars sign and allow up to two decimal?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo Grid that I create like this:

```
function drawInvoiceTable() {
    invoiceTable = $('#invoiceGrid').kendoGrid({
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataSource: {
            data: getData(),
            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'test',
                    fields: {
                        active: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
             { template: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkInvoices' class='invoiceDisplay' name='chkInvoices' #= active ? checked='checked' : '' #/>", width: 30 },
            { field: 'accountNumber', title: 'Account', attributes: { 'class': 'accountnumber' }, sortable: true },
            { field: 'transactionDate', title: 'Trans Date', attributes: { 'class': 'transdate' }, width: 100, sortable: true },
            { field: 'TransType', title: 'Type', attributes: { 'class': 'transType' }, width: 60, sortable: true },
            { field: 'TransReferenceNumber', title: 'Reference Number', attributes: { 'class': 'refnumber' }, width: 135, sortable: true },
            { field: 'transactionDebitAmount', title: 'Amount', attributes: { 'class': 'amount' }, width: 90, sortable: true },
            { field: 'openBalance', title: 'Balance', width: 90, attributes: { 'class': 'balance' }, template: '#= kendo.format("{0:p}", openBalance) #', sortable: true },
            { field: 'discountAmount', title: 'Discount', format: "{0:c}", attributes: { 'class': 'discount', 'data-format': 'c' }, width: 90, sortable: false },
            { field: 'discountApplied', title: 'Discount Applied', width: 95, attributes: { 'class': 'discapplied' }, sortable: false },
            { field: 'paymentApplied', title: 'Payment Applied' , width: 95, attributes: { 'class': 'paymentapplied' }, sortable: false },
            { field: 'discountDate', title: 'Discount Date', attributes: { 'class': 'discountDate' } },
            { field: 'dueDate', title: 'Due Date', width: 90, sortable: true }            
        ]
    });

    grid = $('#invoiceGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    dataSource = grid.dataSource;
    data = dataSource.data();
}
```

How can I have the values in some of my columns formatted with the dollar sign and allow up to 2 decimal such as $12541.23 ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the column definition use `format: "{0:c2}"`:

```
{ field:"price", title:"Price", format:"{0:c2}" },
```

`c` stands for currency and `2` is the number of decimals

Comment: I tried what you suggested above, but still no luck. Please look at my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JFy2C/6/)

Comment: You need to say that the field is of type `number`. See it here http://jsfiddle.net/JFy2C/8/ for `discountAmount` (and other fields) modified.

Comment: Is there any documentation for these format strings? Can't find any

Comment: In case anyone still needs documentation for formatting, it can be found [here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/develop/docs/index.md) under suggested links.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to set the [column.format](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.format) to `"{0:c2}"`
"c2" is the number format (currency, 2 decimal places) which is [defined here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/globalization/intl/numberformatting).

Comment: I tried what you suggested above, but still no luck. Please look at my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JFy2C/6/)